How Are Tezos Fees Calculated for Signing a Transaction?
I’ve been trying to figure out how Tezos calculates fees for signing transactions, but there doesn’t seem to be a single comprehensive document explaining it. If there is one, it’s nearly impossible to find. This lack of clarity makes it obvious why the network is facing challenges.
Here’s an example transaction:
{
  "operation": {
    "branch": "BKirgMJYrgXVUrM3Yk4gjGnv4ccDxZQ8fSz3cdvccvkLc1xxmCd",
    "contents": [
      {
        "kind": "transaction",
        "source": "tz1cuN9Kd3RjQBQTJJ5ttot9zHnWxZYNm19i",
        "fee": "999",
        "counter": "11860976",
        "gas_limit": "169",
        "storage_limit": "300",
        "amount": "7",
        "destination": "tz1hBT7dx9aaiZTEsSJUnB8fKQ76EswyTLgZ"
      }
    ],
    "signature": "edsigtXomBKi5CTRf5cjATJWSyaRvhfYNHqSUGrn4SdbYRcGwQrUGjzEfQDTuqHhuA8b2d8NarZjz8TRf65WkpQmo423BtomS8Q"
  },
  "chain_id": "NetXdQprcVkpaWU"
}

Where is the documentation for the "fee" field? What does it represent exactly, and how is it calculated? The official docs are scattered and hard to understand, often leaving me more confused after reading them.
To thrive, you need a developer-friendly ecosystem. Look at Ethereum: it has a formal yellow paper, excellent documentation, and a simple, useful design. Ethereum's ecosystem makes sense because it caters to developers.
Who wrote this mess (Tezos)? Do they know anything about architecture and software engineering? I highly doubt it! This is frustrating and unprofessional, and it's clear why the network is struggling. Developers are the backbone of a blockchain network, and if they can’t navigate it, the whole thing collapses.
When simulating a transaction, the consumed gas is reported in milligas, while the consumed storage is reported in Tez. This is a glaring inconsistency and creates unnecessary confusion for developers (this was just an example of course). How can anyone work efficiently with such discrepancies? These basic details should have been standardized from the beginning.
my main question: what is the exact definition of the "fee" field?

Looks like a duplicate of https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/how-are-baker-fees-estimated-in-tezos

@RaphaëlCauderlier while the questions are similar, several points raised by the OP are not addressed in that answer, and the answer itself is extremely out of date. More up to date instructions/documentation are warranted. The question should remain open for someone to provide more up to date info

I asked a very specific question, what is the "fee" field definition? how to calculate that?

In order to unblock you for now, i'll point you towards some resources until a more complete answer is provided here

If you are using JS/TS, you can rely on the taquito library to handle all of this for you: https://taquito.io/
If not, you could look at the open source code of Kukai wallet's implementation of this logic here: https://github.com/kukai-wallet/kukai/blob/production/src/app/services/estimate/estimate.service.ts#L97  (This is one of the major wallets in the ecosystem). Hopefully this is something you will be able to work off of. This process is currently quite complex, and often requires updates after new Tezos protocols activate or issues are discovered, so please check back with this code


no I am not using JS/TS, thank you, reading the OCamel code will be nicer that reading JS!

Official doc gives this :
https://tezos.gitlab.io/quebec/consensus.html#fees
https://ex.rs/protocol-level-fees/
is it ok ?

Where does either of these links provide information on how to calculate the fee? Please also note that "link only" answers are discouraged on stackoverflow, as the links may become dead links, leaving future users unable to find the answer

No, this just states that it’s a fee! I already know it’s a fee—the name itself suggests that. I’m a developer, and I need an exact definition, not vague descriptions. What does the fee specifically represent? How is it calculated? What factors contribute to it? I need precise technical details, not superficial explanations.

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/docs/api/quebec-mempool-openapi.json


GET /filter     returns you the minimum fees configured on the node


But the node can configure something else if he wants 


Total fees = minimum fees + gas fees (based on processor time) + storage fees (based on the size of the persistent memory) 

All these values depends on the node choices


@BenjaminFuentes while this is a possibility when looking at this from a protocol level, in practice taking the whole picture into account, this is almost entirely irrelevant to a frontend developer at the moment. Apps have no idea which baker will be selected, and theres no means to broadcast this info. We need to stop providing info to frustrated developers in this manner, and instead provide real world info. This user is asking for sample code or instructions on how to calculate baker, gas and storage fees. Confusing them with irrelevant info only makes the problem worse
